# Is it possible to override application.properties value from azure app settings

Tags: spring, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a dockerized spring boot application as Azure app service using Web app for Containers. My application.properties file has a setting which I need to override after deployment. Is there any way I can make use of "Application settings" section of my app service to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can!

There is [another answer here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806449) works very well for dotnet, whereas in Java/Spring environment all azure app settings are treated as system environment variables and can be accessed via `System.getenv()` ([See also: Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use set application.properties from any source by using the right application events listener.

*org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener*

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartingEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

...

public class AzureApplicationPropertiesListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartingEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartingEvent event) {
        var client = buildAzureIntegrationClient();
        var properties = readApplicationPropertiesFromAzure(client);
        event.getSpringApplication().setDefaultProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

Here (https://www.shardik.com/blog/2020/04/09/azure-properties/) is a tutorial for reading secrets from the Azure Key Vault to use them as Spring application properties.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about spring boot. but a in azure app service context.

AppSettings value in portal will always override, application settings value in the config files.

So any code for eg in .net terms ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"] will return value from the portal, if it exists and override code config file.

Comment: This I know. I am specifically asking about spring boot.